# how to backup an SD card (containig OS) that is *not* properly seen by other computers, except it works fine to boot the OS(!)

Tags: dd, fdisk, gparted, sd-card, parted

I have this RaspberryPi booting from a 32 Gb sdcard. I took it off the RPi to make a back up but the card shows as a `32 Mb` single partition everywhere I plug it.

On my other Raspberry it is listed as 32 Mb in both parted and fdisk

```
$ sudo parted
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print
Error: /dev/sda: unrecognised disk label
Model: Lexar LRWM04U (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 32.1MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
(parted) quit
```

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 30.6 MiB, 32096256 bytes, 62688 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Also my Mac sees this as a 32 Mb. Indeed I have tried to clone the SD card with `sudo dd if=/dev/rdisk4 of=~/pi20211210.img bs=1m` and I got a file of 32 Mb!

If I put this card in the RaspberryPi it works all fine, but how do I back it up if it is not properly recognized by other computers?

Please note I have already tried to use a different SD-USB adapter and two different computers (Mac and another Pi) ...

Here is the output requested by people commenting

```
 $ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    1 30.6M  0 disk
```

```
$ lsblk -m
NAME         SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
sda         30.6M root  disk  brw-rw----
```

```
 lsblk -f
NAME        FSTYPE LABEL    UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda
```

Comment: If you cannot see the partition table, but you can see the card as a drive, a mass storage device, you can clone it to a file, an image file, or clone it to another card, that has at least the same size, not one single byte smaller. If some tool can see its file system(s), there are other options too, to backup at the file level. What is the output of the command `lsblk` and for more details, `lsblk -f` and `lsblk -m` ?

Comment: A cloned image file as well as a cloned copy on another card can serve as backup. It is easy to check that the cloned copy on another card works. In order to use the cloned image, you must first cloned it to another card that has at least the same size, not one single byte smaller. This is enough if there is an MSDOS partition table or no partition table at all, but if there is a GUID partition table (GPT) you must also fix the backup partition table at the end of the drive, because to cards have seldom exactly the same size.

Comment: As the card is seen, barely, as drive and no partitions inside, how should I clone it? As said `dd` makes silly 32mb files, whereas the card is 32gb.

Comment: FYI now the RPi does not boot anymore from this card.

Comment: You wrote "If I put this card in the RaspberryPi it works all fine" and now you write "FYI now the RPi does not boot anymore from this card." - I don't understand. Please explain with more details.

Comment: When I wrote the message the card was good enough to boot, but I could not back it up  because of the strange way it appears on other computers. Now, hours later, after I have put it into several computers several times to try to clone it, now it no longer boots. I hope this is more clear.

Comment: I may still use a tip on how to clone it, despite the partitition table being now probably corrupt or some other sickness that makes it appear 32 mb instead of 32 gb

Comment: Please have a look at the links in my answer. Ask about `ddrescue` if you need help with it ...

Answer (score 0):

If there are valuable data on the card, that are not backed up elsewhere, you need a rescue action. But it will be difficult unless you can make some reader + computer see the whole device, not only 32 MB.

- Maybe `ddrescue` will work, it is rather tolerant, when there are bad sectors, and can clone whatever can be read.
- On the cloned copy, you can try different repair tools, for example TestDisk and PhotoRec from https://www.cgsecurity.org/
- But it is also possible that the internal system of the SD card is damaged beyond what can be repaired with tools available to you and me. Memory cards and USB pendrives can fail without warning. Let us hope that you will be able to clone the whole drive or at least most of it with `ddrescue`.

See the following links.

- [Repair the partition table and file system of a pendrive](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986)

  - scroll down to "Advanced repair of a partition table, file system and/or recovery of files"
- [Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)

  - Analysis of the problem

Comment: I was playing with `TestDisk` while you were writing. It does not provide a hint for a partition table. I tried `Intel/PC` which gave error Partition sector doesn't have the endmark 0xAA55`.

Comment: I have a backup, a bit old, but maybe I can use it to read the exact partition table and copy it onto the card? I am guessing is just the partition table that is gone ...

Comment: Maybe it works. Good luck :-)

Comment: Turns out that the image I wanted to use is not clear it is a good one. I thought it was an outdated backup, but I not even sure at this point, as I have flashed it and it goes into a kernel panic at boot. Maybe still usable to get the partition table ... but need first to sort out if it really is an image of that machine. I tried to `mount` it in Mac OS but only the /boot partition of Raspberry Pi OS is visible. The boot partition does not really help me to see which machine this is for. Will try to get ext4 on Mac OS or a linux machine to read inside this.

Comment: I would say it is easier to use Linux in order to mount and read an ext4 file system.

Answer (score 0):

As I read your question, and the comments, it sounds like your SD card is FUBAR. If so, I know of no way to make a backup - a backup program would need to mount and read the SD card. The only potential salvation might be `fsck`; that's probably a long shot here, but it will only take a few minutes to find out. FWIW, I posted a [procedure for running `fsck` on an SD card](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/119811/83790) a while back.

Re your `lsblk` outputs, I feel that `lsblk --fs` is the most informative, and easiest to read - at least that's been my experience.

At some point in the near future you'll either be lucky enough to recover part or all of your SD card - or - you'll get a new SD card & re-install on that. When you get to that point, you should [consider using `image-utils` to keep your RPi backed up](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/120154/83790).

Comment: just reading a bit about `image-utils` I am wondering where it had been until now and why I had not know about it before! Just the pain of keep buying 32 Gb SD card to avoid huge space waste when saving them with `dd` is a huge pain, having to unmount/powerdown and stick the card into another machine is an even bigger reason to just schedule backups twice a year ... I hope `image-utils` keeps its promises!

Comment: "Where has `image-utils` been?" :) One could conjur many theories on that... perhaps it's because many RPi owners are too dependent on the manufacturer to tell them what to do? But one could also ask why so many cling to [`dd` when it's issues have been thoroughly documented?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A885+dd)

Comment: @RhoPhi: Just saw your [latest question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/682822/286615) on this subject. I won't bother you about this again, but I'm curious about somethings: Did you not find `image-utils` (and this answer) useful at all - or did you decide to stick with `dd`?

Comment: Not tried it yet, as it requires to boot that system and right now I want to limit as much as possible the action on a possibly faulty or neat to fault SD card. Will give it  a try on the new system I have put in place to replace the old machine.

Comment: I have produced an image using `image-backup` from a fresh buster onto which I have put a few servers (mqtt, cups, ...). Backing up with `dd` or `ddrescue` I have got huge image files, 32 Gb!, which are a pain to handle and flash, but they gave me bootable SD cards once flashed back with ddrescue. The image from `image-backup` is only 4 Gb, wow, but it does not give me a bootable SD, the boot process is stuck in loading a serivce rfkill and then goes into emergency mode console. I guess the problem might be due to the default of shriking the fs to the bare minimum ... or that's not a problem?

Comment: anyways the console emerge mode took a while to, in the end, not load ... `cannot opne access to console, the root account is locked`

Comment: @RhoPhi: `image-backup` does produce bootable image files. They must be flashed to your media after the file is created. You can use (for example) Etcher for this - or one of the others.

Comment: I have flashed the image with   `ddrescue`, I am headless, so I think I did the right thing ... did I not?

Comment: I have also flashed it with balenaEtcher, the boot stops at the same place on rfkill, then tries to go onto rescue console, but fails because root account is locked.

Comment: the problem was linked to the need of an external HD on USB to be attached at boot, as explained [here](https://www.htgsd.com/information-technology/fix-rpi-with-cannot-open-access-to-console-the-root-account-is-locked/). I attached the usb drive and it boots! will keep testing!